# Confusion about subsets of Hausdorff spaces being closed or open

Tags: general-topology

> Every finite subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

If $X$ is Hausdorff then in order to prove that every finite subset is closed I can show that the set $\{x\}$ is closed for every $x \in X$ since finite union of closed sets is closed.

Let $y\ne x \in X$ thus since $X$ is Hausdorff there exists $U_x, U_y$ such that $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$. Now this implies that $y$ is not in the closure of $\{x\}$ which further implies that the closure of $\{x\}$ is $\{x\}$ hence it's closed.

This seems a bit weird since every subsets of $X$ are open in $X$. Every singleton in a Hausdorff space has it's own open neighbourhood hence subsets of $X$ are just an union of open sets thus open. What does this mean? Every Hausdorff space is both open and closed?

Comment: You proved every singleton in a Hausdorff space is closed, but not open. So no, there are many interesting Hausdorff spaces, including the real numbers, where not every set is open.

Comment: You may want to reread your topology axioms. Arbitrary **unions** of **open** sets are open. This is not true for closed sets. The equivalent statement for **closed** sets is that arbitrary **intersections** of closed sets are closed. This equivalence is an application of DeMorgan's Laws for union/intersection/complements.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in a **finite** Hausdorff space all subsets are open and closed, indeed. It's a discrete space. All $\{x\}$ are closed; this easily follows from Hausdorffness. So all *finite* subsets are closed because closed sets are closed under finite unions (not arbitrary unions). And all subsets of a finite set are finite etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true that all subsets of a Hausdorff space are open. For example, take $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, nonempty finite sets are not open there. To be honest, I don't really understand your argument to why do you think all sets must be open.